# Shorthand to create a dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of keys and want to create a dictionary that looks as follows:

```
d = {"a":[] ,"b":[] ,"c":[] ,"d":[]}
```

If i try something like this:

```
keys = ['a','b','c','d']
d = dict(zip(keys,[[]]*len(keys)))
```

it creates the dictionary just fine, except all lists are references to the same object, so if I try `d['c'].append('one')` then it gets appended to all four lists.

I solved it using dict comprehension
(for those interested: `d = {k : [] for k in keys}`) but wondering if there's a more efficient way?

Edit: yes I KNOW it's a dict comprehension. That was a typo obviously.

Comment: list comprehension is pretty efficient....

Comment: That's a dict comprehension, not a list comprehension, and it's the standard way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dict comprehensions are pretty efficient (and it is not the *list comprehension* as mentioned by you). I would suggest to go with the dict comprehension. Surely there are few alternatives to achieve this, but they won't be as efficient as the one you mentioned.

Below is the `timeit` comparison of your alternative solution using `zip` (even though I know that it doesn't works the way you expect) and the one using *dict comparison* on Python 2.7:

```
# Using dict comprehension --> 0.415 usec    
mquadri$ python -m "timeit" -s "keys=keys = ['a','b','c','d']" "{key: [] for key in keys}"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.415 usec per loop

# Using `dict`-`zip` conversion --> 1.48 usec    
mquadri$ python -m "timeit" -s "keys=keys = ['a','b','c','d']" "dict(zip(keys,[[]]*len(keys)))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.48 usec per loop
```

As you can see, ***dict comprehension* approach is about three times faster** and I doubt that there is any other more efficient way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

How about [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

data['key'].append('a')
data['key'] # prints ['a']
```

This way you directly skip the dict iteration in the beginning.

Comment: This can work, depending on the use case, but the behavior is different if you try to do `in` tests or access a key not in the `keys` list.

Answer (score 1):

```
keys = ['a','b','c','d']
d = dict((k,[]) for k in keys)
d['c'].append('one')
print(d)
```

You get

```
{'c': ['one'], 'a': [], 'b': [], 'd': []}
```